# How to create a file using touch in Dockerfile or docker-compose?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to create an empty DB file using `touch` by `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml` and volume it. Actually, I'm able to create it manually within the container as follows:

```
docker exec -it <container-name> bash
# touch /app/model/modbus.db
```

Whereas, when I use the following procedure it throws `exited with code 0` and stops:

```
version: '3'

services:
    collector:
        build: .
        image: collector:2.0.0    
        command: bash -c "touch /app/model/modbus.db"  # Note
#        command: bash /app/bashes/create_an_empty_db.sh

        volumes:
          - "./model/modbus.db:/app/model/modbus.db:rw"

        tty: true
```

As well as this, I tried that via `Dockerfile` without any success either:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /
ADD . /app
RUN touch /app/model/modbus.db  # Note
CMD python app
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

Also without the `command: bash -c "touch /app/model/modbus.db"` in the `docker-compose.yml` which was the cause of `exited with code 0`; a directory will be created named `modbus.db` instead of a file due to the following section:

```
volumes:
  - "./model/modbus.db:/app/model/modbus.db:rw"
```

---

TL;DR:

How to send a new file from the container to the host which does not exist in the host? (In other words, it is done inside of the container, not in the host)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the `docker-compose.yml` but the `dockerfile` that you have seems to be working for me.

The `Dockerfile` looks like this,

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /
RUN touch /app/modbus.db
```

Build the dockerfile,

```
docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM python:3.6-slim
 ---> 903e8a0f0681
Step 2/4 : RUN mkdir /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c039967bf463
Step 3/4 : WORKDIR /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c8c81ac01f50
Step 4/4 : RUN touch /app/modbus.db
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 785916fe4cea
Successfully built 785916fe4cea
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

Build the container,

```
docker run -dit test
52cde500cda015f170140ae9e7174a0367b29265a49a3742173946b686179fb3
```

I ssh'ed into the container and was able to find the file.

```
docker exec -it 52cde500cda015f170140ae9e7174a0367b29265a49a3742173946b686179fb3 /bin/bash
root@52cde500cda0:/# ls
app  bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@52cde500cda0:/# cd app
root@52cde500cda0:/app# ls
modbus.db
```

Comment: I updated my question with "creating a file and volume it between the container and the host"

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put the following in your docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - "./model:/app/model"
```

This will create a /app/model folder inside of your container. Its contents (which you will create inside the container) will be available on ./model on your host.

If you put the touch command in the CMD of your Dockerfile, that file will be created after starting the container when the volume is also initialized. So the following Dockerfile should work:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /
ADD . /app
CMD touch /app/model/modbus.db && python app
```

Comment: I updated my question with "creating a file and volume it between the container and the host" - Your manner didn't work with the volume attribute in docker-compose, whereas, when I removed it, it works.

Comment: and it is its related error: `unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type`

Comment: Okay, I think I see what your real problem is now. Updated my answer.

Comment: My problem is that without any `touch` command and just volume command in docker-compose, it creates a folder with `modbus.db` instead of a file, that I mentioned in my question "NOTE"

Comment: so are you sure ./model/modbus.db on your localhost is a file and not a directory?

Comment: There isn't any modbus.db in the host, I want create a modbus.db file in the container and volume it on the host

Comment: Thanks for the response, that was a tricky way (volume all directory instead of a specific file) :D +1